# What is the worst case complexity of the symmetric tridiagonal QR eigenvalue algorithm?

Tags: complexity, eigenvalues

Ignoring eigenvectors, the shifted QR algorithm for computing eigenvalues in the symmetric tridiagional case costs $O(n)$ per iteration, converges globally, and converges cubically near the end.  What is its worst case complexity (which presumably depends on the desired error)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the right shift stategy (mixing RQ and W shift appropriately), it is globally cubically convergent, with a guaranteed linear convergence factor, which makes its complexity of the order of $N$ times the logarithm of the off-diagonal entries. Unfortunately,

See http://www.springerlink.com/content/f1w76x84463l52t7/ for local cubic convergence.

Comment: Does that mean there is no entry-independent worst case upper bound?

Comment: Probably no known one. But my knowledge about this is about 10 years old, so you should check more recent literature.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm not able to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine either.